# Does the verb "grant" comes with "to"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

We may say:

> I give him more value.

or:

> I give more value **to** him.

Now about verb "grant", we may say:

> I grant him more value.

Can we also say:

> I grant more value **to** him.

?

Comment: Well spoken English is all about picking out the best word.  Maybe you can say any of the above and it would be close enough to be understood.  But you don't really *grant* someone value or even *give* them value.  You can assign them value, if the value is coming from you (such as their value to you - how do you rank them in importance to you, who do you value more?), or you can recognize their value, if their value is innate / from something other than you (such as their value in society).

Answer (score -1):

I think

> I grant more value to him

is perfectly good English even if the meaning is a bit odd.

Comment: I think it's actually closer to Evil English.  I mean, it's proper, but I would hardly characterize it as *good*.  Doesn't seem to be much goodness it what is being said - or are you planning to add this text to the Good Book?